# Bean into bean injection

Tags: spring

Have no experience with Spring beans injection.

```
<beans:bean id="ModeService"
        class="<path>Service">
    <beans:property name="Mode" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="Filter"
       class="<path>.RequestFilter">
    <custom-filter position="FIRST" />
</beans:bean>
```

How to inject ModeService bean into Filter bean ?

ok, I've got injection in Spring thx @William
So have:

```
<beans:bean id="maintenanceModeService"
        class="<path>.MaintenanceService">
    <beans:property name="maintenanceMode" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="maintenanceFilter"
       class="<path>.MaintenanceRequestFilter">
    <custom-filter position="FIRST" />
    <beans:property name="modeService" ref="maintenanceModeService"/>
</beans:bean>
```

In MaintenanceService, I've append setter/getter for invoking variable:

```
boolean maintenanceMode;

public void setMaintenanceMode(boolean mode)
{
    this.maintenanceMode = mode;
}

public boolean getMaintenanceMode()
{
    return maintenanceMode;
}
```

And append setter/getter into MaintenanceRequestFilter:

```
boolean modeService;

public void setModeService(MaintenanceService maintenanceMode)
{
    this.modeService = maintenanceMode;
}

public MaintenanceService getMaintenanceMode()
{
    return modeService;
}
```

And then invoke modeService in doFilter()

But smth wrong...

Comment: I solved my problem, it's was just inattentiveness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<beans:bean id="Filter" class="<path>.RequestFilter">
    <custom-filter position="FIRST" />
    <beans:property name="modeService" ref="ModService"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And you should have a getter/setter method in your class

```
class RequestFilter{
    public void setModeService(ModService modService){
        // some set code here
    }

    public ModeService getModeService(){
        // some set code here
        return modService;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated code according your advices, it doesn't work properly. It might be my spaces in Dependency Injection...

Comment: I solved my problem, it's was just inattentiveness :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` attribute to define reference to another bean. `Filter` class should have property of type `ModeService` so that you can define it in `<property>` tag using `ref` attribute.

```
<beans:bean id="Filter" class="<path>.RequestFilter">
    <custom-filter position="FIRST" />
    <beans:property name="modeService" ref="ModeService"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: How to exactly inject ModeService's property <beans:property name="Mode" value="true"/> with Filter's modeService property ?

Comment: @Pilot: using the code I mentioned above.`<beans:property name="modeService" ref="ModeService"/>` will inject `modesrevice` bean.